# Deleting last section row in a Tableview NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm building a generic FetchedResultsController DataSource class to be used on all my TableViewControllers, some of them have multiple sections, some not (like any Project).

The problem is when the Fetched Results Controller have multiple sections (**sectionNameKeyPath** is not null) the delete logic on didChangeObject have to delete the entire section if there is only one row on the TableView section, but the same logic doesn’t work if only one section is set on Fetched Results Controller definition (sectionNameKeyPath = nil).

Anyone know how to implement a generic delete logic on didChangeObject to prevent this kind of error?

**Exception:**

> An exception was caught from the delegate of
>   NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after
>   the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in
>   the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of
>   sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted). with userInfo
>   (null)

```
//Fetched Results Controller Definition on My Model Class
+ (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[self.class entityName]];

    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent = %@", self];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dueDate" ascending:NO]];

    [request setFetchLimit:50];

    //Generate an error
    return [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:Store.defaultManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    //Works Fine
    //return [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:Store.defaultManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"shortDueDate" cacheName:nil];
}


//Fetched Results Controller Generic Data Source Class
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController*)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)newIndexPath
{
    if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert) {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    } else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeMove) {
        [self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath];
    } else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {

        BOOL deleteSection = FALSE;

        //If have only one section and its the last row then delete entire section
        if ((self.tableView.numberOfSections == 1) && ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]] == 1 )) {
            deleteSection = TRUE;
        }

        if (deleteSection) {
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:YES];
        } else {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    } else {
        NSAssert(NO,@"");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry Milz, posted unintentionally! Now is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you implement:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
```

then the FRC will determine for you whether sections need to be inserted or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5.1

I had a similar problem while dealing with NSFEtchedResultsController and CoreData.

1. Override `func tableView(_:, commit:, forRowAt:)`

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if editingStyle == .delete {
       let commit = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

       let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections
       let section = sections![indexPath.section]

       // numberOfObjectsInCurrentSection is the class' variable
       numberOfObjectsInCurrentSection = section.numberOfObjects

       container.viewContext.delete(commit)
       saveContext()
     }
   }
   ```

---

2. Implement this `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method. Here
   you're going to check how many items are left in the previously
   selected table view's section and either remove a single row or (if
   the section only has one row lew) the whole section

   ```
   func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .delete:
       tableView.beginUpdates()

       if numberOfObjectsInCurrentSection! > 1 {
           tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
       } else {
           let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
           indexSet.add(indexPath!.section)
           tableView.deleteSections(indexSet as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
       }

       tableView.endUpdates()
   default:
       break
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is the solution I'm following now.. if you have grouped entities and allow deletion with delete animation.. was looking for a solution without using a global variable, sadly this is the only way that seems to work